# how to pass data upwards from child through an arbitrary amount of parents and changing it each time

Tags: javascript, components, svelte, sveltekit, declarative

How can I pass data from an innermost child component upwards through an arbitrary amount of different parent components, having each parent component modify the data all the way up until the outermost parent renders it?
 
For example, suppose I have some math utilities like `initial(num: number)`, `add(amount: number, num: number)`, and `subtract(amount: number, num: number)` that are used in vanilla js like:

```js
const total = add( 2, subtract( 4, initial(10) ) )
console.log(total) // logs: 8 ie: 10 - 4 + 2
```

How can I create components to use these in a declarative way, like:

```js
<Add amount={2}>
  <Subtract amount={4}>
    <Initial num={10} />
  </Subtract>
</Add>
```

Which would output something like: `<span>8</span>`
 
I would like to be able to use an arbitrary amount of nesting between the different "modifier" components all nested around an initial "data setting" component. See REPL with the vanilla JS implementation: https://svelte.dev/repl/30ce69a25f1b46269e0a9918c84f36aa?version=4.2.0

I’ve tried using context and can’t quite get it to work.

Comment: Why, though? Seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I want to make an existing dependency we have that works like this declarative for use in svelte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a very smart person on the Svelte Discord, I got a working and very elegant solution:

```js
// App.svelte
<script>
    import Add from "./Add.svelte";
    import Subtract from "./Subtract.svelte";
    import Initial from "./Initial.svelte";
</script>

<Subtract amount={2}>
    <Add amount={4}>
      <Initial num={3} />
    </Add>
</Subtract>
// renders `5 <br />`
```

```js
// Initial.svelte
<script>
    import { getContext } from "svelte";

    export let num;
    
    const context_fn = getContext("context_function") ?? ((e) => e);
</script>

{context_fn(num)} <br />
```

```js
// Add.svelte
<script>
    import { getContext, setContext } from "svelte";

    export let amount;
    
    const context_fn = getContext("context_function") ?? ((e) => e);
    setContext("context_function", (arg) => amount + context_fn(arg))
</script>

<slot />
```

```js
// Subtract.svelte
<script>
    import { getContext, setContext } from "svelte";

    export let amount;
    
    const context_fn = getContext("context_function") ?? ((e) => e);
    setContext("context_function", (arg) => context_fn(arg) - amount)
</script>

<slot />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is such an interesting problem.

This [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3409cb05851049b7b8cf2bfb3a7a67e6?version=4.2.0) shows how to accomplish this using Svelte's data binding.

The idea is to expose the required input and calculated output as props, then databind the whole thing.  This is not easy in any way, but does the job.

You'll notice this has "V2" in its name.  My "V1" tried to make use of [slot props](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/slot-props).  It works as well, but it is wordier and I even needed the `tick()` function to synchronize things.

Comment: I agree, it's a good challenge. I was going in the same direction as you with both the binding and the slot props as well as a context version, but just couldn't get a good version working. Someone apparently quite smart on Discord solved it for me very simply with context  https://svelte.dev/repl/d424274105684645a121d070fe2c1582?version=4.2.0 I'll post the details as an answer

Comment: if you have any additional ideas, I also need to be able to accept multiple children as inputs like `<Sum><Number num={1}/><Number num={1}/><Number num={1}/></Sum>` which would return `3`... The vanilla JS `sum` looks like `sum(...numbers): number` and is used like `sum(1, 1, 1) // returns 3`