# how can I access/count the children in a svelte slot?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I need to know how many children are in a `<slot />` is this possible? For example:

```js
// Parent.svelte
<script>
let count = 0 // how to get something like slot.children.count??
</script>
<slot />
```

```js
// Child.svelte
<div>child</div>
```

Usage:

```js
<Parent> // count inside parent should be set to 3
  <Child />
  <Child />
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

Not sure if I"m missing something obvious but I can't find this capability anywhere.

After trying many different approaches without success, I have the rest of the functionality that needs to know the count working by just passing the count, but it really is not ideal:

```js
// Parent.svelte
<script>
  export let count
</script>
<slot />
```

And use like:

```js
<Parent count={3}>
  <Child />
  <Child />
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

But it would be much simpler to be able to calculate the child count to avoid mismatching between the amount of children and the count

Answer (score 1):

If the components can be coupled without causing issues elsewhere, you can define a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#setcontext) in the parent, get it in the child and make it "register" itself there.

Something along the lines of:

```js
// in parent
// Use a store for reactivity
const count = setContext('count', writable(0));
```

```html
<span>Child count: {$count}</span>
```

```js
// in child
getContext('count').update(i => i + 1)
```

You could also query the DOM, though I would not recommend that.

There currently is *no* programmatic access to slot contents, except [checking whether it was set](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#slot-$$slots) at all.

Comment: That is what I'm doing now... I am able to count them no problem. Now I need to run a function with some data from each child but only run it with all the data not for each child. I think I've almost got it working

Comment: You should ask questions about your actual goal, not some small part of what you think you need to do. Maybe your whole approach is not suitable and something else should be done entirely.

Comment: Exactly, this reminds me to a possible [*XY-Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: This was my actual goal... But once I got that working and started integrating it, I realized I also needed to be able to have the parent function run with all children as inputs, for a parent like `<Sum />`, ie: `<Sum><Number num={1}/><Number num={1}/><Number num={1}/></Sum>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062764/how-to-pass-data-upwards-from-child-through-an-arbitrary-amount-of-parents-and-c

Comment: That makes very little sense, you do not need the count for any math operation. Also, most of them should be modelled as just binary for simplicity, as things like subtraction do not work any other way. So what ***is*** your goal, doing math via components?

Comment: Sorry, the goal is to make 1 of our internal deps declarative. It works like this math example. It has 3 function types: `creator(params: object): object`, (Num) `transformer(params: object, ...objects): object | [object]`, (Add) `combiner(...objects): object` (Sum). I want to be able to nest them any which way, like: `<Num init={9}/><Add num={1}><Num init={2} /><Sum><Num init={2} /><Num init={2} /></Sum></Add>`  which results in `[9, 3, 5 ]: [(the root Num val), (root Add val + nested Num val), (root Add val + result of nested Sum)]`

Comment: I can add a REPL with as close as I've gotten if you're able to take a look?

Comment: Either update the question, or create a new one which includes the real problem or something that is actually representative of it. Would recommend the latter, shifting goal posts are not great and more people will probably see the new question. In any case, the comments are not the place for this.